# increasing space between rows of an array

Tags: spacing, arrays

[image]I have the following equation:

‎‎

```
\begin{equation*}‎
    \left\{‎ 
    ‎\begin{array}{lll}‎
    ‎-\mathrm{f}-2,‎ ‎& z_{\left( \mathrm{f}+i\right) \left( j_{1},j_{2}\right) }=-1‎, ‎&‎ 
    ‎S_{\mathbf{z}_{\left( j_{1},j_{2},i\right) }}^{1\-- \mathrm{f}}=-1‎, ‎\\‎ 
    ‎\text{ \ }\mathrm{f}‎, ‎& z_{\left( \mathrm{f}+i\right) \left( j_{1},j_{2}\right) }=+1‎, ‎&‎ 
    ‎S_{\mathbf{z}_{\left( j_{1},j_{2},i\right) }}^{1\-- \mathrm{f}}=-1‎, ‎\\‎ 
    ‎-\mathrm{f}+6,‎ ‎& z_{\left( \mathrm{f}+i\right) \left( j_{1},j_{2}\right) }=-1‎, ‎&‎ 
    ‎S_{\mathbf{z}_{\left( j_{1},j_{2},i\right) }}^{1\-- \mathrm{f}}=\text{ \‎ }%
    ‎7‎, ‎\\‎ 
    ‎\text{ \ }\mathrm{f}+8‎, ‎& z_{\left( \mathrm{f}+i\right) \left( j_{1},j_{2}\right) }=+1‎, ‎&‎ 
    ‎S_{\mathbf{z}_{\left( j_{1},j_{2},i\right) }}^{1\-- \mathrm{f}}=\text{ \‎ }%
    ‎7,%‎
    ‎\end{array}%‎
    ‎‎\end{equation*}%
```

how can I increase the space between rows of this array without use `\\`‎‎ ?

Comment: `array` is intended for arrays and matrices not for a multi-line display , you could use `\arraystretch` but better would be to use a `cases` environment from `amsmath`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't bother fine-tuning the settings of the `array` environment. Instead, I would use the dedicated `dcases` environment, provided by the `mathtools` package, as it is tailor-made for situations such as yours. (The "`d`" in "`dcases`" stands for "display style" math mode.)

Observe the use of several `\phantom` statements to adjust some of the character positions. I've also gotten rid of all `\left` and `\right` modifiers since they do nothing except provide code clutter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for "dcases" environment
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}‎
‎\begin{dcases}‎
    ‎{-}\mathrm{f}-2,‎ 
    ‎& z_{( \mathrm{f}+i) ( j_{1},j_{2}) }=-1‎, ‎\quad‎
    ‎S_{\mathbf{z}_{(j_{1},j_{2},i) }}^{1-\mathrm{f}}=-1‎, ‎\\‎
    \phantom{‎-}\mathrm{f}\phantom{{}-2}‎, ‎
    & z_{( \mathrm{f}+i) ( j_{1},j_{2}) } =+1‎, \quad‎
    ‎S_{\mathbf{z}_{(j_{1},j_{2},i) }}^{1-\mathrm{f}}=-1‎, ‎\\‎
    ‎{-}\mathrm{f}+6,‎ 
    ‎& z_{( \mathrm{f}+i) ( j_{1},j_{2}) }=-1‎, ‎\quad
    ‎S_{\mathbf{z}_{(j_{1},j_{2},i) }}^{1-\mathrm{f}}= \phantom{-}7‎, ‎\\‎
    \phantom{‎-}\mathrm{f}+8‎,
    ‎& z_{( \mathrm{f}+i) ( j_{1},j_{2}) }=+1‎, ‎\quad
    ‎S_{\mathbf{z}_{(j_{1},j_{2},i) }}^{1-\mathrm{f}}= \phantom{-}‎7,‎
\end{dcases} 
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I use `dcases` in the following equation?
`\begin{equation*}‎
‎\begin{array}{ll}‎
‎\chi \left(‎ -‎1\right) =-1‎, ‎& \mathrm{f} =3‎, ‎\\‎ 
‎\chi \left(‎ -‎1\right) =+1‎, ‎& \mathrm{f} =1,%‎
‎\end{array}%‎
‎\end{equation*}`

Comment: @FahimB - Piece of cake: `\begin{equation*}‎ ‎\begin{dcases}‎ ‎\chi(-‎1)=-1‎, ‎& \mathrm{f}=3‎; ‎\\‎ ‎\chi(-‎1)=+1‎, ‎& \mathrm{f}=1. ‎\end{dcases}‎ ‎\end{equation*}`. Oh, and for sanity's sake, *please* cease using `\left` and `\right` in front of each and every parenthesis. It's simply not correct usage! Who taught you this bad habit?! Please unlearn it.

Comment: @micro Thank you very much. I wrote this text first by scientific workplace and these `\left` and `\right`  are from that software. I hope to ride this habit.
Is it possible to ride `{` from the left of `decases`?

Comment: @FahimB - my userid is Mico, not Micro.